# A GUI program that converts a collection of images to a film

Tags: windows-7, gui, animation

I'm looking for a program that:

- Has a GUI
- Is free (= gratis/libre)
- Works on Windows 7
- Can import still frames (i.e. images) and animate them
- Can add audio to said animation

Naturally, I need options to change frame rate, duplicate certain frames, etc., but those come with most animation programs.